# Change Color onClick and background on Focus

Tags: android, listview, material-design, drawer

i have a ListView in my Navigation Drawer and want it looks like the Playstore App or Youtube App.

Means onClick changing FontColor for Example to red and when i just hold it the background should turn grey.

Do i have to use 2 onitemclicklistener?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="48dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/DrawerListIcon"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_home"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:textColor="@color/DrawerListFontColor"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Tried with Item and Selector. First thing Font Color don't change when i pressed the Button. Second the background of the Relative Layout turns blue insead of Grey.

drawer_list_font.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:color="@color/DrawerListFontColorPressed"
    />
<item android:color="@color/DrawerListFontColor"/></selector>
```

drawer_list_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:color="@color/DrawerListBackgroundFocused"
    />
<item
    android:color="@color/DrawerBackground"
    /></selector>
```

I had to use android:drawable instead of background on the relative Layout. On the Textview Android Stuio accepted android:color.

Answer (score 0):

This is changed by changing view from ur java file at every click event u can change the view. U have to make multiple view ie xml files for that. Which are dynamically changed or u can also send parameters to a function and create an xml at runtime but that will be too deep for u

Answer (score 0):

No need for listeners at all.
A better approach here is to create drawable XML's with definitions for every state ("pressed", "focused", etc).
Check out [Color State List resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource)

For example:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false"android:color="#80000" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ff0000" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ff0000" />
    <item android:color="@color/DrawerListFontColor" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Ok thanks. This was what i am looking for. Unfortunaly it doesn't work so well. Can you tell me what's wrong. See at my first post.